# SQL Server 2005 PIVOT Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I receive the following error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

When I run the following query

```
 SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM
(
SELECT [TimeStamp],[MeterID],[Value]
FROM access_AMIData) AS source
PIVOT
(
SUM(Value)
FOR MeterID IN (SELECT MeterNumber FROM access_tblFcppPvMeterList)
) as pvt
ORDER BY TimeStamp
```

The error comes with this line:

```
FOR MeterID IN (SELECT MeterNumber FROM access_tblFcppPvMeterList)
```

If I change this line to:

```
FOR MeterID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

It works perfectly...how can I specify a select Query inside the IN?

Comment: That is not true it does work

Comment: It won't even pass syntax check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5182). If you change it to `[1],[2],[3],[4]`, then it works.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable workaround to have the columns be generic 1, 2, 3, 4, but in fact holding the values for the first four meters?  That's possible using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  You could even have the meter numbers in columns parallel to the results: 4:54 PM | Meter 123 | $50 | Meter 456 | $75.  If you'd like to share more about the ultimate goal, there may be alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not in SQL 2005.  You could include it in the WHERE clause of your inner query, but you have to hard-code the column names, unless of course you use dynamic SQL.